# If for $F \in \mathcal{F}$ there is countably many $A_n$ such that $F=\bigcup_{n} A_n$ show that $\sigma (\mathcal{F}) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A}).$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ are subsets of the power set of some set $X$. If for each $F \in \mathcal{F}$ there exists countably many $A_n$ such that $F=\bigcup_{n} A_n$ show that $\sigma (\mathcal{F}) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A}).$

If I take the union of all $F_i \in \mathcal{F}$ I have that $$\mathcal{F}= \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty F_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$$

but how do I manage to get that $\sigma (\mathcal{F}) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A}) $? I assume I don’t have any properties where I could just take the sigma-algebras $\sigma(\mathcal{F}) = \sigma(\sigma(\mathcal{A}))= \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ even though this would kind of make sense since $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is the smallest sigma-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$ so $\sigma(\sigma(\mathcal{A}))=\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, but this is probably nonsense.

Comment: $\mathcal{F}$ is not an element of itself, and you can't write it as $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty F_i$. Anyway, to solve your problem it is sufficient to show that $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, (can you see why?) and this is very easy to show.

Comment: If $\forall F\in \mathcal A,\exists \{A_n\}_n\subset \mathcal F: F=\bigcup_{n}A_n$, then $\mathcal F\subset \sigma (\mathcal A)$, and thus $\sigma (\mathcal F)\subset \sigma (\mathcal A)$.

Comment: So I should have that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty F_i \subset \mathcal{F}$? This would seem that since $\ \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty F_i  = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i  $ I have an element that’s in $\mathcal{F}$ and also in $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$? @Mark

Comment: $\mathcal{F}$ itself is just a collection of sets. Elements of $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty F_i$ are elements which belong to elements of $\mathcal{F}$. So most of the time this union will not be contained in $\mathcal{F}$, leave alone equal to it. But this has nothing to do with the exercise. You just need to show that $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, which is straightforward.

Comment: Perhaps I’m walking in circles here so apologies, but then $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty F_i$ would cover $\mathcal{F}$? Since this cover is in $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, then wouldn’t it be immediate that $\mathcal{F} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{A})$?

Comment: **Is** $A_n\in\mathcal A$? That's obviously what you meant, but if you mean that you need to _say_ so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that those $A_n$'s are elements of $\mathcal{A}$. We show that $\mathcal{F} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{A})$. We know that for arbitrary sequence $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathcal{A} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ then $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$. Since for $F \in \mathcal{F}$ there $\exists (A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathcal{A}$ s.t. $F = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ then $F \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ which implies $\mathcal{F} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ and by definition of smallest $\sigma$-algebra, $\sigma(\mathcal{F})\subset \sigma(\mathcal{A})$.